# Upload of a Pandas DataFrame to Google Cloud Storage is adding unwanted empty lines

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a DataFrame to Cloud Storage and then to BigQuery, but I keep getting errors on the BigQuery import. I believe this is because the file I have written to Cloud Storage had unwanted empty lines. e.g.

I'm expecting this to be written to the file:

```
product, quantityWarehouse, quantityStore
'12345',1,3
```

But instead I get the following:

```
product, quantityWarehouse, quantityStore

'12345',1,3
```

This is my code:

```
my_data = pd.DataFrame([['12345',1,3]],columns=["productId", "quantityWarehouse", "quantityStore"])
my_data.to_csv("gs://my_bucket/my_data.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Do you have the option to write your data frame directly to BigQuery? If so this may simplify the solution?

Comment: I do, but this issue shouldn't be occurring

Comment: I ran the above code and I'm not getting the same output as you. I get `productId,quantityWarehouse,quantityStore` first line and `12345,1,3` second line, without the added newlines and without the spaces in the first row.

Comment: Can you post your error?

Comment: even if you open the file in excel?

Comment: I'll try to get the BQ error again

Comment: @user147529 you can try to use _line_terminator=""_, like this: _**my_data.to_csv("gs://my_bucket/my_data.csv", header=fieldnames, index=False, line_terminator="")**_ . You can check this link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: didn't work, my colleague tried on dataproc, and it's working fine

Comment: I tested your code and it's generating a normal csv without any empty row. Perhaps the problem is in your BigQuery load job

Comment: no the load job works for my colleague. There might be an issue with some python or package configuration. When I upload to GCS from my machine, it's adding the empty lines, but on other people's machines, it's not there

Comment: Could you try to add `my_data.to_csv("foo.csv", index=False)` and check if your local file is different than the one uploaded to the bucket? This way we may narrow down where the issue originates.

Comment: I think I was having the same problem locally too, so it's not actually GCS I think. I will double check to confirm

Comment: Please share your results once you check it out

Comment: It's only google cloud storage. locally is ok, although there is an extra line at the bottom locally

Comment: Can you please share bigquery error? I tried your code and it worked perfectly. Python 3.7, pandas 0.25, gcsfs 0.6. May be try updating pandas.

Comment: The bigquery error is irrelevant. The problem is that it's posting extra rows. It may well be my version of python. I'm using python 3 though. thank you

Comment: Then try upgrading pandas and gcsfs, may be older versions add this rows. Otherwise I don't see what can be wrong, I've tried exact same code and had no issues, no added empty rows, and uploaded file from GCS to BQ successfully.